# Android SharedPreference : I am unable to save information

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am new to android and I have tried Below code to save my country when back is pressed or App killed.

```
//Code
public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
    if (picker.getId() == R.id.countrypicker) //
    {
        Country selectedCountry = BigBoss.getInstance().countries[newVal];
        BigBoss.getInstance().currentCountrySelected = selectedCountry;
        TextView tvcountry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countryval);
        tvcountry.setText(selectedCountry.name);
        String a = (String) tvcountry.toString();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit().putString("namec",a);
        edit.apply();
    }
```

Comment: But this is not working

Comment: have you called this method frm onBackPressed() or onStop() method?

Answer (score 0):

You need a ref variable for the editor before putting any data. Replace these lines:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit().putString("namec",a);
edit.apply();
```

With these:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("namec",a);
editor.apply();
```

Comment: Thanks for Your Reply but I tried this as well but nothing happens,I have a TextView infront of Country which displayes the country being choose form Picker Now when I scroll the Wheel and choose a country the Selected country appears in front of Country but when i hit back the name of the country disappears ..tvcountry is that TextView .

Comment: By nothing happens you mean that when trying to get this string you receive null?

Answer (score 0):

edit.commit()
 Please try this, i think it may be help you.

Comment: Welcoem to Stack Overflow.  Please explain how this helps.

Comment: SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
edit.putString("key", "value");
edit.commit();                                                                               Try this way.

Comment: Thanks All it helped me